# Нужна ли запятая после "ну-ка"?

Tags: пунктуация

Ну-ка вылезай из машины! А ну-ка вылезай!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово ***ну-ка***, как и слово ***ну***, выражает призыв или побуждение к действию. Оно может обособляться как междометие или не обособляться как частица. В устной речи это соответствует наличию или отсутствию паузы.

***Ну-ка*** не обособляется, если в требовании присутствует **категоричность** (частица имеет значение **усиления**): ***Ну-ка вылезай из машины! А ну-ка вылезай!***

Если ***ну-ка*** выражает только побуждение к действию, то слово по значению ближе  к междометию. Тогда оно  произносится с паузой и обособляется: ***Ну-ка, отойди в сторонку.***

**Примеры:**

Нет запятой:

**Ну-ка** сядь на стул и послушай...  [Виктор Астафьев.  «Новый Мир», 2000]

Однажды бабушка пришла с катушкой белых ниток и сказала мне: «**А ну-ка** встань»... [Герард Васильев. Роли, которые нас выбирают (2002)]

Запятая ставится:

**Ну-ка,** расскажите, что вы помните об этом годе. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей / Приложение (1964)]

Уже спокойнее они сказали Арсению: **Ну-ка,** перекрестись. Арсений перекрестился. [Евгений Водолазкин. Лавр (2012)]

Answer (score 1):

Нет, запятых не нужно. На [Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D1%83) *"ну-ка"* указано как междометие, и после него и *"ну-кась"* нету запятой:

> **Ну-ка;** *(нар.-разг.)* **ну-кась; ну-кася, в зн. межд.** Выражает призыв или побуждение к действию. *Ну-ка почитай мне. Ну-кась поговорим.*